# Bind to a Name property of a grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

So I have my xaml:

```
<Grid 
       Name="{x:Static enums:DropTargetNames.ItemsGridView}" />
```

So the `enums` is the namespace, the `DropTargetNames` is a static class and the `MasterProgramGridView` is a static string. The idea being to prevent mistypes when coding, because these get used in multiple places.

Unforatunately c# WPF doesn't allow this. So is there another property I can set like this to use as an identifier for the grid?

My code identifying the grid is this:

```
var grid = dropInfo.Target as Grid;
var name = grid.Name;

switch (name) {

}
```

In the switch you use the `DropTargetNames.ItemsGridView` or other static strings.

Comment: If you're reusing them, maybe it would make sense to reuse whole controls instead of just a name? You can create a template/style and reuse that. I believe that makes much more sense..

Comment: I would rather just be able to apply a name, other grid views may want that name and I dont want to mess them up if they're already using templates and styles. Just want to add a name

Comment: Maybe you can use `Tag` property, it's used to store custom information for an element.

Comment: Yeah that sounds good! @SimonChan

Comment: Would be interested to know why you'd need to identify a grid by name in code, as data binding normally/often takes away the need to grab a UI element in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end, I went with the comment about tag. That was exactly what I needed:

```
<Grid Tag="{x:Static enums:DropTargetNames.ItemsGridView}">

</Grid>
```

C#:

```
var grid = dropInfo.Target as Grid;

switch (grid.Tag as string)
{

}
```

All good!

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting it indirectly through an AttachedProperty, lets say in a class called ABC

Lets say that the attached property is declared like this

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DynamicNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DynamicName", typeof(object), typeof(FrameworkElement), new PropertyMetadata(default(object), PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        FrameworkElement frameworkElement = (FrameworkElement)dependencyObject;
        if (eventArgs.NewValue != null)
        {
            frameworkElement.Name = eventArgs.NewValue.ToString();
        }
    }
```

In XAML you could set the name like this

```
<Grid 
   prefix:ABC:DynamicName="{x:Static enums:DropTargetNames.ItemsGridView}" />
```

Comment: That seems like an interesting solution. It does seem a bit much, if the tag solution fails I'll use this. Thanks